# AS3 / Stopping timer at a Vector?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, timer

How do i start my timer at vector[2] and stop it at vec[13]. `myTimer.stop();`

I have done that the vector jumps to the next vector every 10 seconds (timerevent).  The timer and vector will continue to count and then goes back to the vec[0]

If possible, I would like to start my timer at a later vector. And that the timer stops at the end.

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.repeatCount = 13;
myTimer.delay = 1000;

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownHandler);
function  countdownHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{   
    countdown.text = 0+myTimer.currentCount+" s remaining";
    countdown2.text = 0+myTimer.currentCount+" s remaining";
    if(myTimer.currentCount==10)
    {
        myTimer.reset();
        myTimer.start();

    }   
}
myTimer.start();
```

&

```
function timerfunctie(event:TimerEvent) 
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < vec.length; i++) 
    {
        if (vec[i].parent) if (myTimer.currentCount == 9) 
        {
            removeChild(vec[i]);
            var next2:int = i+1;
            if(next2 == vec.length) next2 = 0;
            addChild(vec[next2]);
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where timerfunctie is called, but this code should detect when the currentCount of the timer is 2 and 13.  If you want the Timer to run the full 13 iterations, you do **not** want to reset it at iteration 10.

```
function  countdownHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{   
    countdown.text = 0+myTimer.currentCount+" s remaining";
    countdown2.text = 0+myTimer.currentCount+" s remaining";

    if (myTimer.currentCount==2) {
        // start with vector[2]
    } else if (myTimer.currentCount==13) {
        // end with vector[13]
    }
}
```